# Add another, existing attribute first (on top) in the existing attributes list on product admin page WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product, admin

[image]I have a large list (30 to 50) of attributes on every product admin page. Is there a function that changes the order of a new added attributes in the existing list of attributes? i.e. I would like to have added every new attribute on top (first) instead of the bottom (last) in an existing attributes list. Please see the screnshot attached.